# Backslash replace issues in Wordpress posts

Tags: wordpress, post, wordpress-gutenberg

I have over 300 occurence for a url with backslash in over 200 of wordpress posts. I ahve tried using better search and replace plugin to search for it in database but the plugin didn't return any search result talkless of replacing them.

The line /url is:

`<a href=\"https://hiideemedia.com/konga\" target=\"_blank\">hiideemedia.com/konga</a>`

Please is there any way out to get rid of the \ (backslash) in the line above please???

I have tried using better search and replace plugin but not solving the problem